# How do I use Compass sprites?

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I've been messing around with Compass, using the Scout GUI, for a day now and sprites are driving me crazy.

Compass is creating the sprite but it seems the CSS is pointing to the wrong place.

The import statement looks like:

```
@import "images/icon/*.png";
```

And, here's how I'm calling it:

```
            h1{

    @include icon-sprite("social");
```

The link that is getting created in the CSS is:

```
http://localhost/images/icon-s25f42076dc.png
```

I would like it to be:

```
http://localhost/compass/images/icon-s25f42076dc.png
```

This is my config.rb:

```
http_path = ""
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
relative_assets = true
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out: 
Import path needs to be 
@import "../compass/images/icon/*.png";

Comment: problem somehow came back. getting error: Compass::SpriteException on line 84 of C: No files were found in the load path matching "../compass/images/icon/*.png". Your current load paths are: C:/wamp/www/compass/images/icon      any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change 'relative_assets' to false.